# If $f(z) = e^{1/z}$ show that for any $\epsilon > 0$ and any $w\neq 0$ there exists a $z$ s.t. $|z|<\epsilon$ and $f(z)= w$.

Tags: complex-analysis

I am struggling to prove of the following theorem:

[image]
I tried the following:

I need to prove that for all $\epsilon$ > 0 there exists a $|z|$ such that $|f(z)|= w$.

$e^{1/z}=w$
so $z=\frac{1}{\log(w)}$

So we need

$0<|\frac{1}{\log(w)}|<0$

$0<\frac{1}{|\log(w)|}<0$

$0<\frac{1}{|\log|w|+i\arg(w)|}<0$

I don't know how to proceed from here.
Could somebody please help me? Thank you!

Comment: The fact that a holomorphic function assumes every value of $\mathbb{C}$ (with a possible single exception) in any neighborhood of an essential singularity is exactly Great Picard's Theorem. (Of course, you don't need this full result to answer the problem!)

Answer (score 1):

Take $z_0\in\mathbb C$ such that $e^{z_0}=w$. Then, for every $n\in\mathbb N$, $e^{z_0+2n\pi i}=w$. Take $n$ large enough so that $\left\lvert\frac1{z_0+2n\pi i}\right\rvert<\varepsilon.$ and let $z=\frac1{z_0+2n\pi i}$.